Minimum right for AWS IAM User to invoke Bedrock API
I am new to AWS but I plan to access LLMs on Bedrock via AWS API. I already made the root user and an IAM user.
I am struggling with what rights should I assign to the IAM user to be able to make API requests to Bedrock. I already granted full rights to Bedrock (AmazonBedrockFullAccess) but the API calls still fail (no permission). Something is missing, what could it be?
I tested my PHP code (aws-sdk) with the root account's key and it worked.

Add the IAM policy you gave the IAM user to your post. Also, be aware of the recommendations about the account root user.

@jarmod I added the policy to the description. Yes, I am aware of the root account risks. That is why I want to access the API by using IAM user.

Well, a simple test to determine if the issue is genuinely that your IAM user does not have sufficient permission is to add AdministratorAccess temporarily. If that does not work then you may be mis-reading something.

@NikoSuominen, share the code, the error message, and the policies you have added for your iam user.

@ArpitJain I got it working. The code was fine but it was the 403 issue.
I made a new IAM user only for Bedrock purposes with AmazonBedrockFullAccess. I generated the key and secret and the API call worked. My previous trial had the problem that I had made an IAM Identity Center user which was unsuitable for this purpose. I am still learning the different user types on AWS.
